# Monitor of Azure Express Route

Tags: networking, azure, monitoring, containers

I would like to monitor our Express Route. There is a good description on how to do this on Microsoft learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/how-to-configure-connection-monitor

But this requires Virtual machines/Servers on each side for the connections that should be monitored. Having full virtual machine for only connection tests seems a bit much and we don't really want to share machines..

I am wondering if it is possible to have these agents installed in docker containers instead. That way we can use our kubernetes cluster instead wich is much more economical. Have anyone tried this type of setup. Would be nice to know its possible before I dig too much time into it.

Answer (score 1):

Connection monitor is feature to monitor connectivity from and to a VM.

I think you need to look at expressroute network insights
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-network-insights

Comment: Thank you for the response I will look into this if it can solve out monitoring need. One other option that we are exploing now is to setup a connection monitor to monitor http traffic from the azure VM to a local http site that we know are up. Like intranet. that means we don't need extra VM.. Even if we depend on the intranet being up.

Comment: You can also use Azure Monitor directly to monitor an Express Route https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-monitoring-metrics-alerts